# ListLinePlot much slower when using smaller PlotRange on y axis

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, timing

Using 11.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit). This should be pretty self-explanatory.

```
data = RandomInteger[1000, {30, 10000}];
Timing[ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All];]
(*{1.752, Null}*)

Timing[ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{1000, 9000}, All}];]
(*{1.844, Null}*)

Timing[ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {All, {100, 900}}];]
(*{20.66, Null}*)
```

Is this because a lot of disconnected lines need to be drawn? Is there a way to fix or circumvent this?

Answer (score 2):

You can see what is going on better if you do a smaller example:

```
data = RandomInteger[1000, {30, 10}];
Timing[g1 = ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All];]
Timing[g2 = ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {All, {400, 600}}];]
```

Then type

```
FullForm[g1]
```

and

```
FullForm[g2]
```

As you suspected, the expression for `g2` is much more involved, as there are a lot of short segments.  Not only does it take a lot more memory to store all of those segments, the computer had to calculate all of those line breaks.  Starts getting expensive for a large number of segments.